# How to include arguments in a function pointer?

Tags: c++, function-pointers

How can I include arguments in a function pointer?

This code creates a function pointer that can add two ints:

```
int addInt(int n, int m) {
    return n+m;
}
int (*functionPtr)(int,int);
functionPtr = addInt;
(*functionPtr)(3,5); // = 8
```

For instance, I want to make a function pointer where the first argument is always 5, so that the function takes one int and adds five. And another one where the first argument is 8.

Is this possible using `addInt`? Something like:

```
// make-believe code that of course won't work 
int (*functionPtr)(int);
functionPtr = addInt(5);
(*functionPtr)(3); // = 8
(*functionPtr)(9); // = 14
```

Comment: You can't, not with function pointers anyway. You can however use [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) to do it.

Comment: why do you need a function pointer if you are going to add that value to something anyway?  BTW there are no default values for functions, only constructors

Comment: @Pandrei This was a minimal example, not my actual problem

Comment: @Anna: you probably should have asked about your actual problem, and you certainly should mention if you are coding in C++11, C++14 or some older versions of the C++ standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `std::bind` like this:

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
auto f = std::bind(addInt, 5, _1);

f(1); //returns 6
```

Answer (score 3):

What you really want is a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29) (you might also want curryfication, but C++ don't have that; consider switching to Ocaml if you really want it).

[C+14](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++14) and [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) have closures (but not earlier versions of C++). Read about C++ [lambda functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) (or anonymous functions) and the standard [`<functional>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/functional) header and its [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) template.

Here is the function which given some integer `d` returns the translation by `d` i.e. the function taking an integer `x` and returning `x+d`

```
#include <functional>
std::function<int(int)> translation(int d) {
  return [=](int x) { return addInt(x,d) /* or x+d */ ; };
}
```

Notice that `std::function`-s are *not* just C function pointers. They also contain closed values (`d` in my `translation` example)

The [auto](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) and [decltype](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) specifiers are tremendously useful.
For example:

```
auto addfive = translation(5);
std::cout << addfive(3) << std::end; // should output 8
```

Comment: I think using `auto` instead of `std::function<int(int)>` would be better, at least if you get to assign it where you declare it like that.

Comment: @Hunkyl: Are you sure? I would believe that for a newbie expliciting `std::function` is more readable!

Answer (score 3):

Use std::bind and placeholders

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

int addInt(int n, int m) {
    return n+m;
}

int main() {
    int (*functionPtr)(int,int);
    functionPtr = addInt;
    (*functionPtr)(3,5); // = 8
    auto f2 = std::bind( addInt, std::placeholders::_1, 5);
    auto f3 = std::bind( addInt, 8, std::placeholders::_1);
    std::cout << f2(1) << "\n";;
    std::cout << f3(1) << "\n";;
}
```

Output:
   6
   9